# Fontawesome causes render deploy to fail

Tags: deployment, font-awesome, web-deployment, strapi, render.com

I am deploying my strapi application with render.com and I always run into this problem regarding fontawesome after the command `yarn install` has run.

it's giving me a 401 unauthorised for a fontawesome free package which shouldn't be happening I don't think.

[Render error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOft2.png)

I have tried removing `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` and locally ran `yarn install` again but none of it makes a difference every time I push to GitHub and the deploy re-runs.

If you need any more information please let me know!

If you have a solution or can point me in the right direction for one please let me know :) Thank you!

Comment: I encountered this problem before. Basically I did the following: Remove yarn.lock and node_modules (as you did), then push (without running yarn install locally! - this push should delete yarn.lock from your repo) and then the pipeline (it was on Heroku) finally built. I don't know what caused the problem but as long as my yarn.lock wasn't in repo, my deploy was success.

Comment: ahh kinda makes sense. Ill give that a go and ill let you know. Thank you for commenting :)

Comment: Hey, just letting you know that worked! Thank you for helping @KarelKřesťan

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)